# DAX - SUM latest 20 values by product

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need your help.
In the table below I need to SUM the LATEST two units by date for each region.
in other words:
[image]

If we take region="central" I need to make a measure or calculated column which sum the latest two units (= 1+2). 
In other words, this is the result I want:

[image]

now, I have tried to make the DAX code below in a calculated column, but with this I only get the last "unit"-value for each region?

```
Measure = 
var _region = Sheet1[region]
var _orderDate = Sheet1[dato]
var _prevDate = MAXX(FILTER(Sheet1; Sheet1[dato] > _orderDate && Sheet1[region] = _region); Sheet1[dato])
var _result = LOOKUPVALUE(Sheet1[units]; [region];_region; [dato];_prevDate)
return _result
```

Result:

[image]

Does anyone know how I get to sum the latest two units for each region?

I will really appreciate a solution.

thanks.

Br,
Jakob

Comment: The [`TOPN` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/topn-function-dax) may be helpful for this.

Comment: Hi Alexis, yep it worked. Thanks a lot.